# How to acces model from inside directive when model changes in controller $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to get when the value inside the directive changes from outside and it seems it does not work with either scope.$watch or attrs.$observe.

I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/alexrada/x3U6V/).

```
angular.module('zippyModule', [])
  .directive('elem', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
        transclude:true,
        template:"Directive: <span ng-repeat='i in values'>{{i}} </span>",
      scope: { values:'=zippyTitle' },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         attrs.$observe ('zippyTitle',function(newValue){
             console.log (scope.values);
         });
          scope.$watch ('values',function(newValue){
             console.log (scope.values);
         });

      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to watch content of an array (and not its reference) you need to use deep-watch by passing `true` as the last argument to the `$watch` method:

```
scope.$watch ('values',function(newValue){
             console.log (scope.values);
}, true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dVzCP/

With the latest AngularJS (1.1.4) things are becoming a bit easier as there is a new method (`scope.$watchCollection`) specifically created to shallow-watch elements of a collection:
[http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection)